# eth0 always connects on power up but fails to reconnect after restart

Tags: 14.04, networking

My Ethernet connection to a Netgear R6300 *always* connects correctly after a few seconds at power up.

This problem first showed up on Fedora 21 after updates.
 * reloaded from disc, all OK.
 * Installed updates - no LAN connect. (Tried Centos 7, same result.)

Then I installed Ubuntu 64bit: OK; Updated: OK until next restart then *again eth0 never connects*, though it's perfect full power down/up.

What I've checked already:

- Router(server) appears to be configured OK for DHCP operation.
- All wireless devices-IPADS, nooks, chromebook, wireless laptop (Windows 7) OK
- All LAN devices, Windows 8.1 desktop, Sonos bridge, Old Thinkpads running MINT 17.1,and/or PCLINUXOS function without a problem.

Please note there are never more than 2 Ethernet cards connected at once.

The exception is the year old home-built PC running UBUNTU 14.04  (legacy boot).
Build:

- Intel DH87RL MOBO
- Intel 4570 CPU (Haskell I5)
- Integrated NIC
- 840 EVO SSD (500 GB)
- Integrated graphics and sound

After restart the network indicator shows it is trying to connect wirelessly and when opened will allow disconnect but not connect to LAN.
   Have suspected NIC or interaction from program or kernel (updates?) nojoy
   dmesg didn't leap out and pinpoint anything other than log that it didn't connect.
   Router log shows one blocked - I think that was an attempt to open a Linux counter to add my machines to the count-firefox and it saw it as an attack site.

Sorry to give you so much. Hope someone can make a connection.
   Have ordered NIC card as next try.

*Confused and in need of enlightenment!*

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! More information would be helpful. The chipset of your NIC might shed some light. Anything of interest in syslog? output of `sudo lshw` pertaining to the NIC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution provided by firmware update on Jan 08 from Ubuntu..I believe it to be the NIC related firmware update 127.1.10 to 127.1.11.
At any rate I consider it resolved.

Comment: Fantastic!  (Why didn't I think of that!)  ;-)  Don't forget to accept your own answer in a few days!